# Stored Procedure Functions

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have two tables 
Equipment(equipmentid, equipname, equipstatus, maxrentdurationdays)**EquipmentID**
Equipment_Hire(equipmentID, pickupdate, dropoffdate,clientNo)
I need to create a stored function that takes clientNo as input and adds up 20$per day if the equipment_hire table's dropoffdate-pickupdate > MaxRentDurationdays

I was getting errors while doing this in oracle 11g.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Fines
(P_ClientNo Equipment_Hire.ClientNo%TYPE)
RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
V_ClientNo INTEGER;
V_DURATIONDEFD INTEGER;
V_TOTALFINE INTEGER;
BEGIN   SELECT ClientNo, MAXDURATIONDAYS
INTO V_FName, V_LName, V_TotalSalary
FROM Equipment, Equipment_hire
WHERE P_CLientNo = Equipment_Hire.ClientNo;
IF Equipment_hire.dropoffdate-equipment_hire.pickupdate > 
equipment.maxdurationdays THEN
Equipment_hire.dropoffdate-equipment_hire.pickupdate*20
RETURN Equipment_hire.dropoffdate-equipment_hire.pickupdate*20; ELSE
RETURN 'Date UNSPECIFIED';
END IF; END Fines;
```

Data: https://www.mediafire.com/?chl6fdcl9cs817w

You can only use two tables equipment, equipment_hire.

Comment: Don't you want to calculate $20 per day by the number of days after the dropoff date to the current date?

Comment: stored function that takes as input a client ID and returns the total fine based on the difference between the total days of rent and maximum allowed rent duration of an equipment. Different values of fine should be generated for a particular client if the function is executed on different dates. 
 This is the task I'm more confused with data. Please help me out.

Comment: What are you getting for errors?

Comment: Error(4,2): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol " " when expecting one of the following:     begin function pragma procedure subtype type <an identifier>    <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> current cursor delete    exists prior external language The symbol " " was ignored.

Comment: You have some issues in your code. for example, what should `IF Equipment_hire.dropoffdate` do? This could only work if you had a variable `Equipment_hire` with a field `dropoffdate`, but you can not access a table this way. I would suggest you to start with some tutorial or simple example on how to get a value from a table and do some logic on its values.

Comment: 1) please format your code 2) please add the error message

Answer (score 0):

Formatting the code helps:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Fines(P_ClientNo Equipment_Hire.ClientNo%TYPE)
RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
  V_ClientNo INTEGER;
  V_DURATIONDEFD INTEGER;
  V_TOTALFINE INTEGER;
BEGIN
  SELECT ClientNo, MAXDURATIONDAYS
  INTO V_FName, V_LName, V_TotalSalary
  FROM Equipment, Equipment_hire
  WHERE P_CLientNo = Equipment_Hire.ClientNo;

  IF Equipment_hire.dropoffdate - equipment_hire.pickupdate > equipment.maxdurationdays THEN
    Equipment_hire.dropoffdate - equipment_hire.pickupdate * 20
    RETURN Equipment_hire.dropoffdate - equipment_hire.pickupdate * 20; 
  ELSE 
    RETURN 'Date UNSPECIFIED';
  END IF;
END Fines;
```

On a quick glance:

- You select two columns, but your INTO clause contains three variables.
- You are cross joining the tables. Who ever told you to use this out-dated join syntax anyway?
- The cross join leads to multiple result rows that you cannot read into simple variables.
- What is that first line after the IF supposed to do?
- You are using table names and columns outside the query.
- Multiplication has precedence over subtraction (or should have). So you are taking a date, multiply it by 20 and subtract the result from another date.
- You seem to think that there is just one equipment hire you are dealing with, but can't a user have several hires?